# Is there a way to disallow users from moving directories?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a shared directory on Windows Server 2008 that is shared between about 15 people. In the root of the share are folders corresponding to the clients my company has. Someone keeps dragging folders in the root of the share into other folders when they are trying to open them, causing them to get lost. Is there a way to set the permissions on this share to not allow moving of folders in the root only?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but this will effectively remove their permissions to modify files in the root also.

First you'll want to make sure there are no explicit permissions in the share folder.  Under the Security tab click Advanced and check for any explicit permissions on the right hand column.  Usually, they are all inherited.  If there are explicit permissions, then copy them down.

Then change the Security settings of the root of the Share folder and turn off write permissions. But turn off the "Propagate properties to child objects."

You'll need to go into each child folder and add in the explicit permissions from before.